# laravel onetomany / belongsto

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I have the following structure (not editable) in my db:

```
-- Table 'computers'
---------------------------
id, operatingsystems_id

-- Table 'operatingsystems'
---------------------------
id, name
```

One computer can have one operating system (One to One), but one Operating system can have many Computers (One to Many)

I have defined the following, Am I doing it the wrong way ?

```
class Computer {
    protected $table = 'computers';
    public function operatingSystem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('OperatingSystem', 'operatingsystems_id');
    }
}

class OperatignSystem {
    protected $table = 'operatingsystems';
    public function computers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Computer', 'operatingsystems_id');
    }
}
```

Because the problem is that when I do

```
Computer::find(1)->operatingSystem()->get()
```

I get a Collection

Answer (score 0):

Try using in the relationship:

```
return $this->hasOne('OperatingSystem', 'operatingsystems_id');
```

And then you can use:

```
$os = Computer::find(1)->operatingSystem;
```

Comment: shouldn't I use a relationship and the reversed one with belongsTo ? That's what I understand from the documentation

Comment: I use hasOne, because I think it's more explicit. In the way you have you can also use first() instead of get and you'll always get one item and not a collection.